# list comprehension c условием 'if not in'

Tags: python

Можно ли сделать list comprehesion из следующего кода в в теле функции:

```
def func(l):
    li = []
    for i in l:
        if i not in li:
            li.append(i)
    return li
```

Если нет, тогда почему?
Спасибо!

Comment: Если порядок не важен, то можно просто set использовать.

Comment: спасибо! list(set(l)) да это решение я знаю. Хочется понять почему не работает List comprehension в указанном выше случае

Comment: Короткий ответ - list comprehension не может обратиться к списку, который он создает. Фактически для list comprehension этого списка еще не существует.

Answer (score 3):

list comprehesion не должен иметь [побочных эффектов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), а обращение к `li` - это работа с  *состоянием*. Если не нужно сохранять исходный порядок элементов, то решается ваша задача элементарно: `li = set(l)`.

Comment: @nich123 я уже написал, list comprehesion не должны иметь побочных эффектов.

Comment: а почему здесь нет побочного эффекта:  `def func(l):
    li = []
    for i in l:
        li.append(i*5)
    return li`  `def func1(l):
    return [i*5 for i in l]`

Comment: @nich123 в `func` есть, но там императивный цикл, которому это позволительно. В `func1` нет, так как `l` служит входными данными, обращений к каким-либо другим данным внутри _включения_ не происходит и единственный результат его работы - список, возвращаемый из функции и зависящий только от входных значений.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, идеологически list comprehension не должен иметь побочных эффектов, но технически может (но за такой код нужно отрывать руки)): https://ideone.com/HZDDnw

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension не может обратиться к списку, который он создает, т.к. этого списка во время работы list comprehension еще не существует.

- Когда вы заполняете список обычным циклом, вы сначала создаете пустой список, потом добавляете к нему элементы.
- Когда вы создаете список через list comprehension - эта конструкция просто генерирует набор элементов, потом эти элементы собираются в список.

Comment: у меня был такой вариант: `def func1(l):
    return [i for i in l if i not in]` выглядит логично :)

Comment: @nich123 не сказал бы. "not in" - "не входит" (в список, например). В вашем примере "не входит" во что, в закрывающую скобку? В любом случае, операторы in / not in всегда требуют второй операнд.

Comment: ну почему в скобку? в список []

Comment: @nich123, там нет списка, только закрывающаяся скобка. В любом случае, так не работает.